# How can i use systemctl to start up a python program on startup in raspbian

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi, services, systemd

I have a python program that receives some data from a different device and prints it to the console. I want to make this program run on startup, the way I read online to do so is by creating a service inside of `etc/systemd/system`

I provided the following settings in the service file

```
[UNIT]
Description=Python file to run on boot
After=multi-user.target

[SERVICE]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/pythonFile.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However I get the following error when trying to start the service

```
Failed to start python-script.service: Unit python-script.service has a bad unit file setting
```

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All specific errors related to unit file loading are logged into the system log; `journalctl -b` will show them (in theory, `journalctl -u python-script.service` should as well).

But *most likely* the error is shown because your .service unit is missing a `[Service]` section. Systemd configuration parameters are case-sensitive – `[SERVICE]` and `[UNIT]` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, to confirm should it be [Service] / [Unit] instead of [SERVICE] / [UNIT] ?